# How to use calc() in svg x attribute with Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, safari

I have created svg component in React, like this:

```
const SVG = ({
    text = '',
    x = '',
    y = ''
}) => (
    <g>
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x={x} y={y} height="70" width="40">
            <text style={{ fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontSize: '30px', fontStyle: 'bold', fill: '#636363' }} textAnchor="middle" x="15" y="25" width="10">{text}</text>
            <g>
                <svg version="1.1" viewBox="90 -500 1000 1000" xml={{ space: "preserve" }} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <style type="text/css">
                    </style>
                    <g>
                        <polygon style={{ fill: '#EDEDED' }} points="500,875 125,125 875,125  " />
                        <polygon style={{ fill: '#191919' }} points="807.6,166.7 500,781.8 192.4,166.7  " />
                        <polygon style={{ opacity: 0.2, fill: '#FFFFFF' }} points="500,875 375,625 406.1,593.9 781.9,218.1 875,125  " />
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg >
        </g>
    );
```

And I use it like this:

```
<svg width="100%" height="130">
    <defs>
         <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
              <stop offset="20%" stopColor="red" stopOpacity={1} />
              <stop offset="45%" stopColor="yellow" stopOpacity={1} />
               <stop offset="100%" stopColor="green" stopOpacity={1} />
         </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <svg x="5%" y="10" width="90%">
       <rect x="0" y="60" width="100%" height="40" fill="url(#Gradient)" />
    </svg>
    <SVG x={`calc(${percentage} - 15)`} y="15" text={currentDays} />
</svg>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, but in Safari I get error:

`Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute x="calc(65% - 15)"`

How can I get this work in Safari?

Comment: x is a presentational attribute and also x can't be (for now) manipulated in css

Comment: also x should have no effect on outermost svg elements. So not sure how you were planning to use that?

Comment: @enxaneta in Safari? Any workarounds or ideas?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I modified the question, its not the outermost svg.

Comment: @enxaneta Even if here OP is apparently not using CSS , note that most modern browsers already have implemented the part of SVG2 which makes `x`,`y` and some others  now [presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes)  and settable through CSS (at least on geometry). Safari supports this for quite  long time now.

Answer (score 3):

Safari (and Firefox) still don't support setting [CSS mathematical-expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#calc-notation) where <percentage-length> values are allowed, as it is for [`x` and `y` coordinates attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/geometry.html#X).

```js
console.log('check your browser console to see error messages');
```

```html
<svg>
  <svg x="calc(20 + 30%)">
    <rect x="calc(30 + 20%)" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Since the `<svg>` element on which you are setting the `x` and `y` attributes, is not a Geometry Element, you can't even set its `x` through CSS (not even in Chrome):

```css
.outer:hover > svg {
  x: calc(20px + 30%); /* fails */
}
.outer:hover > rect {
  x: calc(20px + 30%); /* works */
}
```

```html
mouse over the &lt;svg> to move it by CSS<br>
<svg class="outer">
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
  <rect x="0" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

So instead of setting these attributes, you could translate this content through CSS.
Though Safari doesn't allow us to transform inner <svg> through CSS... So we need to change this element to a <g> one.

```css
svg:hover > g {
  transform: translateX( calc(20px + 30%) );
}
/* Safari is so buggy that we even need an explicit default value */
svg > g {
  transform: translateX( 0 );
}
```

```html
mouse over the &lt;svg> to move it by CSS<br>
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

So in the end, your component should generate a `<g>` instead of a `<svg>` and it should set its inline `style="transform: translateX( {{ x }} )"`, though I'm really not sure of Angular's syntax.

Comment: Im not sure do I understand, I'm not using CSS. And what I'm doing here is working in Chrome, so I'm not sure do I follow what you mean by this can't be done even in Chrome, shouldn't this be working in Chrome?

Comment: @MJICT `calc` notation as attribute values is not supported anywhere else than in Chrome. That used to be a CSS only thing. `x` and `y` can now sometimes be set by CSS, for instance on a `<rect>`, but not the ones of an `<svg>` element, not even in Chrome.

Comment: but I am setting the `x` and `y` values of `<svg>` and it is working in Chrome?  Why its working, if that's something that can't be done?

Comment: ...please read the answer and the comment again. You can set **the attributes** to `calc()` in Chrome but not in others. You can set the CSS to `calc()` in all. You can't set x and y of <svg> through CSS.